# Realtek RTL8188EE drivers in Xenial?

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, realtek

I just updated my pre-Secure Boot, pre-UEFI* Toshiba **2012 Satellite P755-S5390** laptop from 15.10 to 16.04. In 15.10, the wireless adapter worked fine. Now, Ubuntu refuses to acknowledge my laptop has a wireless interface. I've rebooted many times, done the following:

```
apt install flashrom librtlsdr* nictools* r8168-dkms rtl-sdr rtl8812*
```

Which seemed to be successful, and a plethora of other things I've found on the 'net all to no avail. The `Additional Drivers` screen of `Software and Updates` has one entry, which it either claims is `unknown` or `not working correctly`.

[image]

`Network Settings` is short an entry (on the left, there used to be a "Wifi" device or so):

[image: asdasd]

(Before you ask, no, the little plus sign is not helpful.)

I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761160/realtek-wireless-hard-blocked) where a user was having a similar issue, and they posted much data from a plethora of commands, so I'll do the same here.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ uname -a
Linux mint-kitty 4.2.0-36-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP 
Mon Apr 18 15:49:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
02:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
02:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller (rev 30)
02:00.4 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller (rev 30)
03:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)


$ rfkill list all
<no output>

$ sudo lsmod  |grep rtl
rtl8188ee              86016  0
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8188ee
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee
mac80211              745472  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8188ee
cfg80211              557056  2 mac80211,rtlwifi


$ ifconfig
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:88:e3:12:0f:00  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enx7a2df60b7f7a Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7a:2d:f6:0b:7f:7a  
          inet addr:192.168.42.149  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6b2f:6a3c:64e2:5193/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22512 errors:3 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:3
          TX packets:27524 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12577406 (12.5 MB)  TX bytes:5778094 (5.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:533078 (533.0 KB)  TX bytes:533078 (533.0 KB)

$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enx7a2df60b7f7a
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enx7a2df60b7f7a
192.168.42.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enx7a2df60b7f7a

$ iw reg get
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

$ iwlist channel
lo        no frequency information.

enx7a2df60b7f7a  no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

$ iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx7a2df60b7f7a  Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

$ cat /etc/modules
coretemp

# the following commands all return the error code 1
$ dmesg | grep rtl
1 | $ dmesg | grep wifi
1 | $ dmesg | grep wl
1 | $ dmesg | grep rtlwifi
1 | $
```

That `enx7a2df60b7f7a` device is my laptop's tether to my smartphone, which is how I'm writing this post.

How do I get my `wlp2s0` / `wlan0` wireless interface back?

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
<no output>
$ lspci -knn | grep net -A2
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1179:fc30]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

That is the `eth0` physical ethernet device. My wireless card is referenced in `/var/syslog`:

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e wlan0
Apr 25 08:43:32 mint-kitty kernel: [    7.498388] rtl8188ee 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

OK, that's before the update, but there it is.

As suggested here: [How to get Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01) wireless card working on Debian Wheezy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170941/136107)

```
$ locate rtl8188ee | grep -v "debug" | grep .ko
/lib/modules/4.2.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
/lib/modules/4.2.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
/lib/modules/4.2.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
$ sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
insmod /lib/modules/4.2.0-36-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.2.0-36-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.2.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.2.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.2.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
```

But the wifi adapter still doesn't work after a reboot.

---

*My laptop never had UEFI and still has just BIOS; as a result my problem is not the same as [Realtek driver RTL8723BE not working in Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760970).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've edited my question

Comment: I do not see any wireless adapters. Is it a USB adapter? Then post output of `lsusb`.

Comment: @Pilot6 That's the issue. No, it is not a USB adapter, it is built-in.

Comment: Then post full output of `lspci`.

Comment: @Pilot6 Ok, I changed it to show the full output rather than snipped.

Comment: @Pilot6 I found a question on U&L which has given some progress, but not much.

Comment: Please add model of laptop.

Comment: @SteveRoome It's now in bold at the top. :)

Comment: All is wrong in your output. There is no wireless adapter in `lspci`. The kernel version is not from Ubuntu 16.04. You probably use Mint or some other distro.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am aware there's no wifi adapter in lspci. It's connected to the motherboard, however. The kernel version is indeed from 15.10 and hasn't changed since I updated to 16.04. I do use Ubuntu (albeit Lubuntu), not Mint. Mint doesn't even have the 4.2.0.36 kernel. I put `uname` and `lsb_release` in there, too; this is 16.04.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has 4.4 kernel version.

Comment: @Pilot6 According to apt, my system is up-to-date.

Comment: @Pilot6 Now I'm running kernel 4.4.0-22, but I still don't have wifi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not know if you've seen this post already or not but here goes. [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452315/problems-with-realtek-rtl8188ee-on-14-04)

According to the answers in that question, it seems there is a better driver available by a third party developer who maintains it in GitHub.

So open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and follow these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git dkms
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd /path/to/rtlwifi_new
make
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8188ee
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: So, yes, I did try this, I didn't add it to my question because nothing appears to have changed after doing so. I'll upvote it because it will probably be helpful to others with this issue.

Comment: I found it here first: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314434/comments/14

Comment: Bounty gotta go someplace :)

Comment: No, it is going to you, that's what I meant c:

Answer (score 2):

So, the other answer about installing the drviers from source is definitely the right one if you don't have the driver.

In my case, all I had to do was

- take apart my laptop to make sure the wireless adapter was *actually* connected
- put it back together
- reboot a few times
- idly toggle the **Enable WLAN** setting in the BIOS to **off***
- ???
- I now have WiFi.

*Yeah, that's probably a bug. Hopefully this helps another Satellite P755 owner out there.

Comment: I have the same `RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controlleesr` and tried the above method. Still my connection is not persistent. There is a packet loss if I do a ping. Result: `165 packets transmitted, 163 received, 1% packet loss, time 164241ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.053/11.794/131.199/16.516 ms.` What can be a further debugging I can perform to solve this problem?