# Enable wifi option disappeared in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 17.04

WiFi was working fine and after restart **Broadcom** option in additional driver also disappeared and also enable WiFi option. 
Ethernet is working fine.
I tried this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763508/realtek-rtl8188ee-drivers-in-xenial)

and still no progress

all information in this [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24432263/) of my laptop

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 it doesnot show any thing

Comment: I do not believe. Do not type it, copy and paste.

Comment: yes  copy and paste, that's what i did

Comment: Listen, your script that you posted in your questions shows that there is `Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)`. I just asked to give 1 more line of that record. This means that the script is not from your comp, or you do some error with the command.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24433161/  this line

Comment: The controller disappeared. It is disabled in BIOS or broken.

Comment: I followed link from here 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

so what does it mean?
I hava disabled safe boot in bios

Comment: Check if wireless is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: there is no such option in bios.

Comment: It should be there, may be called differently. Otherwise the adapter is just broken.

Comment: there is one called Internal Network Adapter Boot . is it that?

Comment: for two days after booting , wifi was working fine then next day gone. 
I tried ndiswapper but nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57536/discussion-between-pilot6-and-rashim-catalan-dhaubanjar).