# Realtek rtl8188ee Wifi Card not working with ubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, realtek

Just installed Ubuntu on my laptop yesterday and the WiFi card is not working. I have followed countless threads and solutions but none of them seem to work. The solutions that I have found on this site usually end with having to initiate a make command that does not work. This is the thread I mainly followed https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2162026. With this solution the make always fails.This is what happens when I try to do it

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build M=/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o
In file included from /home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:32:0:
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/wifi.h:1005:40: error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  struct ieee80211_supported_band bands[IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS];
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:39:0:
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/pci.h:247:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl_pci_probe’
 int __devinit rtl_pci_probe(struct pci_dev *pdev,
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:137:10: error: ‘IEEE80211_BAND_2GHZ’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  .band = IEEE80211_BAND_2GHZ,
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:149:10: error: ‘IEEE80211_BAND_5GHZ’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  .band = IEEE80211_BAND_5GHZ,
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:318:12: error: assignment to expression with array type
  hw->flags = IEEE80211_HW_SIGNAL_DBM |
            ^
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:331:13: error: assignment to expression with array type
   hw->flags |= IEEE80211_HW_SUPPORTS_PS |
             ^~
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:365:4: error: ‘struct ieee80211_hw’ has no member named ‘channel_change_time’
  hw->channel_change_time = 100;
    ^~
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_action_proc’:
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:885:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’; did you mean ‘chandef’?
       rx_status.freq = hw->conf.channel->center_freq;
                                ^
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:886:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’; did you mean ‘chandef’?
       rx_status.band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                                ^
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_beacon_statistic’:
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:1160:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘compare_ether_addr’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (compare_ether_addr(hdr->addr3, rtlpriv->mac80211.bssid))
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_send_smps_action’:
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:1451:24: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’; did you mean ‘chandef’?
   info->band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                        ^
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_store_debug_level’:
/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:1684:8: error: implicit declaration of function ‘strict_strtoul’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  ret = strict_strtoul(buf, 0, &val);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o] Error 1
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/darren/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-19-generic'
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/907771/665251 See if this helps

Answer (score 0):

My wifi is officially working.I followed the thread that celticwarrior posted [Realtek RTL8188EE drivers in Xenial?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763508/realtek-rtl8188ee-drivers-in-xenial). After trying the solution that was posted in that thread everything was successful but my wifi still wasnt showing up.So i took my laptop apart and put it back together. After doing that my wifi began to work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reassembly was inconsequential and all you missed was a proper system reboot.

Answer (score -2):

Check to be sure your device is supported by Ubuntu, if not you will need to use the windows driver with NDISWrapper to install it and force it to run in Ubuntu.

Here is some information pertaining to that:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-device-drivers.html

Looks like your issue has been resolved in this forum:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2162026

Check it out.

Comment: Could you please include the crucial part(s) of the linked resource(s) in your question in case they change or disappear? Link-only answers are deprecated on AskUbuntu and likely to be deleted. Thanks.