# how do i get a networkManager on a machine with no network

Tags: networking, network-manager, bluetooth, ethernet

In trying to fix Bluetooth with installing a bluetooth package then deleting it.

Now I have no network

```
lshw -class network
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network Controller 
product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
*-network DISABLED
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8101/6E PCI Express Fast /Gigabit Ethernet controller
```

not sure what to do because there is no interface working.

```
sudo lshw -C network 
[sudo] password for   
 *-network UNCLAIMED        
      description: Network controller 
      product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter 
      vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
      physical id: 0 
      bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0 
      version: 01 
      width: 64 bits 
      clock: 33MHz 
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list 
      configuration: latency=0 
      resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0200000-f0203fff 
 *-network DISABLED 
      description: Ethernet interface 
      product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller 
      vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
      physical id: 0 
      bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0 
      logical name: eno1 
      version: 07 
      serial: a0:48:1c:0b:29:53 
      size: 100Mbit/s 
      capacity: 100Mbit/s 
      width: 64 bits 
      clock: 33MHz 
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation 
      configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed
=100Mbit/s 
      resources: irq:31 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff memory:f0010000-f001ffff
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show all of `sudo lshw -C network` as it relates to the ethernet interface only. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Is there any improvement with the terminal command: `sudo dhclient -v eno1`

Comment: Thank you I now have Ethernet. But how do I get Network Manager working and wifi. sorry its been a long day and been away from Unix. memory isn't what is was.

Comment: More to the point how do I claim the wifi rtl8188ee?

Comment: Now walking through this https://askubuntu.com/questions/763508/realtek-rtl8188ee-drivers-in-xenial

Answer (score 0):

Now that the ethernet is working, let's reinstall Network Manager. It comes in a few versions so we'll have to do some guesswork. Please open the terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

See if you can then start it:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

Post any errors or warnings.

I think the link you posted for wireless is probably correct.

Comment: I gave up and reinstalled. Network-Manager is working perfectly, not sure how he corrupted it but looks like 3 Bluetooth packages loaded and then deleted plus cat nocking laptop off counter messed it up bad. I will be putting all your suggestion in my list of troubleshooting tool. Thank you so much for all the help!