# 18.04 Realtek RTL8188EE says "Connection Activation Failed" after about some hours of WiFi use

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10, realtek-wireless

After the Realtek RTL8188EE in my Ubuntu 18.04 system tells me "Conection Activation Failed", I cannot see a single Access Point anymore. The only solution is to restart with `sudo reboot` then everything works fine until the next few hours then "Connection Activation Failed".

`sudo lshw -C network
  *-network

       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 74:29:af:86:b5:1b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=5.3.0-42-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.177 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:49 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b2500000-b2503fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 08
       serial: 38:63:bb:a2:c2:b2
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b2404000-b2404fff memory:b2400000-b2403fff`

I run a dual boot with Windows 10. I tried updating the Windows 10 (since I almost never use it), it still did not make difference.

Edit:
I ran `sudo rfkill list && sudo lspci -knn` and got

`0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller [8086:0a04] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller [103c:227f]
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [103c:227f]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [103c:227f]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series USB xHCI HC [103c:227f]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 [8086:9c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series HECI [103c:227f]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series HD Audio Controller [103c:227f]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:9c10] (rev e4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:9c12] (rev e4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:9c14] (rev e4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:9c16] (rev e4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 [8086:9c26] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series USB EHCI [103c:227f]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller [8086:9c43] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series LPC Controller [103c:227f]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:9c03] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [103c:227f]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller [8086:9c22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series SMBus Controller [103c:227f]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188EE mini-PCIe card [103c:197d]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
    Kernel modules: rtl8188ee
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:227f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169`

I also decided to "look at the logs" using `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

It recently failed so I look at the logs. Any thoughts?

`-- Logs begin at Sun 2020-01-05 11:46:39 WAT, end at Fri 2020-04-03 23:42:53 WAT. --
Apr 03 23:39:50 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [11828:1:0403/233950.585522:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matchin
Apr 03 23:39:50 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [11828:1:0403/233950.587088:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matchin
Apr 03 23:40:06 daniel-pc kernel: rtlwifi: AP off, try to reconnect now
-- Logs begin at Sun 2020-01-05 11:46:39 WAT, end at Fri 2020-04-03 23:42:53 WAT. --
Apr 03 23:39:50 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [11828:1:0403/233950.585522:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matchin
Apr 03 23:39:50 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [11828:1:0403/233950.587088:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matchin
Apr 03 23:40:06 daniel-pc kernel: rtlwifi: AP off, try to reconnect now
Apr 03 23:40:07 daniel-pc kernel: wlo1: Connection to AP ec:84:b4:84:90:f1 lost
Apr 03 23:40:07 daniel-pc wpa_supplicant[964]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=ec:84:b4:84:90:f1 reason=4 locally_generated=1
Apr 03 23:40:07 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <warn>  [1585953607.0978] sup-iface[0x55c5c0885240,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Apr 03 23:40:07 daniel-pc wpa_supplicant[964]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Apr 03 23:40:07 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953607.1923] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Apr 03 23:40:07 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953607.1927] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr 03 23:40:08 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [2040:2058:0403/234008.194971:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(420)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Apr 03 23:40:09 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
Apr 03 23:40:12 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953612.8014] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Apr 03 23:40:12 daniel-pc dbus-daemon[937]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requ
Apr 03 23:40:12 daniel-pc systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Apr 03 23:40:13 daniel-pc dbus-daemon[937]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 03 23:40:13 daniel-pc systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Apr 03 23:40:13 daniel-pc nm-dispatcher[11883]: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Apr 03 23:40:13 daniel-pc nm-dispatcher[11883]: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Apr 03 23:40:13 daniel-pc whoopsie[1228]: [23:40:13] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 03 23:40:13 daniel-pc whoopsie[1228]: [23:40:13] offline
Apr 03 23:40:14 daniel-pc whoopsie[1228]: [23:40:14] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 03 23:40:16 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [11902:1:0403/234016.247909:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matchin
Apr 03 23:40:16 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [11902:1:0403/234016.249232:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matchin
Apr 03 23:40:22 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <warn>  [1585953622.7610] device (wlo1): link timed out.
Apr 03 23:40:22 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953622.7840] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 03 23:40:22 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953622.7844] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 03 23:40:22 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953622.7847] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc nm-dispatcher[11883]: req:2 'down' [wlo1]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <warn>  [1585953623.0326] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'erhabor'
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc whoopsie[1228]: [23:40:23] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc nm-dispatcher[11883]: req:2 'down' [wlo1]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]: New session
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953623.0361] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc nm-dispatcher[11883]: req:3 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]: [ Thread-3 ] java.io.IOException: Unexpected EOF while reading header line
-- Logs begin at Sun 2020-01-05 11:46:39 WAT, end at Fri 2020-04-03 23:42:53 WAT. --
Apr 03 23:39:50 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [11828:1:0403/233950.585522:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matchin
Apr 03 23:39:50 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [11828:1:0403/233950.587088:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matchin
Apr 03 23:40:06 daniel-pc kernel: rtlwifi: AP off, try to reconnect now
Apr 03 23:40:07 daniel-pc kernel: wlo1: Connection to AP ec:84:b4:84:90:f1 lost
Apr 03 23:40:07 daniel-pc wpa_supplicant[964]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=ec:84:b4:84:90:f1 reason=4 locally_generated=1
Apr 03 23:40:07 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <warn>  [1585953607.0978] sup-iface[0x55c5c0885240,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Apr 03 23:40:07 daniel-pc wpa_supplicant[964]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Apr 03 23:40:07 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953607.1923] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Apr 03 23:40:07 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953607.1927] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr 03 23:40:08 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [2040:2058:0403/234008.194971:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(420)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Apr 03 23:40:09 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
Apr 03 23:40:12 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953612.8014] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Apr 03 23:40:12 daniel-pc dbus-daemon[937]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requ
Apr 03 23:40:12 daniel-pc systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Apr 03 23:40:13 daniel-pc dbus-daemon[937]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 03 23:40:13 daniel-pc systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Apr 03 23:40:13 daniel-pc nm-dispatcher[11883]: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Apr 03 23:40:13 daniel-pc nm-dispatcher[11883]: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Apr 03 23:40:13 daniel-pc whoopsie[1228]: [23:40:13] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 03 23:40:13 daniel-pc whoopsie[1228]: [23:40:13] offline
Apr 03 23:40:14 daniel-pc whoopsie[1228]: [23:40:14] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 03 23:40:16 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [11902:1:0403/234016.247909:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matchin
Apr 03 23:40:16 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [11902:1:0403/234016.249232:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matchin
Apr 03 23:40:22 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <warn>  [1585953622.7610] device (wlo1): link timed out.
Apr 03 23:40:22 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953622.7840] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 03 23:40:22 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953622.7844] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 03 23:40:22 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953622.7847] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc nm-dispatcher[11883]: req:2 'down' [wlo1]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <warn>  [1585953623.0326] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'erhabor'
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc whoopsie[1228]: [23:40:23] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc nm-dispatcher[11883]: req:2 'down' [wlo1]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]: New session
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953623.0361] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc nm-dispatcher[11883]: req:3 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]: [ Thread-3 ] java.io.IOException: Unexpected EOF while reading header line
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]:         at xdman.util.NetUtils.readLine(NetUtils.java:18)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]:         at xdman.monitoring.Request.read(Request.java:16)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]:         at xdman.monitoring.MonitoringSession.serviceRequest(MonitoringSession.java:499)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]:         at xdman.monitoring.MonitoringSession.run(MonitoringSession.java:528)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]: [ Thread-7 ] java.io.IOException: Unexpected EOF while reading header line
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]:         at xdman.util.NetUtils.readLine(NetUtils.java:18)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]:         at xdman.monitoring.Request.read(Request.java:16)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]:         at xdman.monitoring.MonitoringSession.serviceRequest(MonitoringSession.java:499)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]:         at xdman.monitoring.MonitoringSession.run(MonitoringSession.java:528)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gnome-shell[1253]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc avahi-daemon[957]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::bb7c:4e38:e796:472 on wlo1.
Apr 03 23:40:24 daniel-pc xdman.desktop[3092]: New session
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gnome-shell[1684]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc avahi-daemon[957]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::bb7c:4e38:e796:472.
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953623.0968] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1151
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc avahi-daemon[957]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953623.0969] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed bound -> done
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc dbus-daemon[1245]: [session uid=121 pid=1245] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.13' (uid=121 pid=1253 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-she
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953623.1312] dhcp6 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc dbus-daemon[1245]: [session uid=121 pid=1245] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gsd-sharing[1806]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-user-share-webdav.service not loaded.
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc avahi-daemon[957]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.177 on wlo1.
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gsd-sharing[1806]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc avahi-daemon[957]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.177.
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gsd-sharing[1806]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc avahi-daemon[957]: Interface wlo1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gnome-shell[1253]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 03 23:40:24 daniel-pc nm-dispatcher[11883]: req:3 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gnome-shell[1253]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gnome-shell[1253]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gnome-shell[1253]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gnome-shell[1253]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gnome-shell[1684]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gnome-shell[1684]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gnome-shell[1684]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gnome-shell[1684]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 03 23:40:23 daniel-pc gnome-shell[1684]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 03 23:40:25 daniel-pc NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1585953625.8612] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Apr 03 23:40:33 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [2040:2058:0403/234033.166550:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(420)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Apr 03 23:41:24 daniel-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1684]: [2040:2058:0403/234124.759660:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(420)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Apr 03 23:42:53 daniel-pc sudo[12020]:   daniel : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/daniel ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl --since=-7 minutes
Apr 03 23:42:53 daniel-pc sudo[12020]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)`

But I'm not sure what I'm looking out for.

Comment: Windows 10 is completely separate and Ubuntu does not even tough its files much less try to use its drivers. Please run _sudo rfkill list && sudo lspci -knn_ and highlight the resulting text. Copy that as text then come back here, click [edit], and paste the result as text into your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Realtek RTL8188EE drivers in Xenial?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763508/realtek-rtl8188ee-drivers-in-xenial)

Comment: Look at the logs: `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`, or within 5 minutes of the failure, `sudo journalctl --since="-7 minutes"`

Comment: @K7AAY, no it doesn't because the driver from (https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new ) is not updated for ubuntu.